# gnuplot command not working with system() function in C++

Tags: c++, gnuplot

My gnuplot command is not working in my C++ program. I am trying to run gnuplot command in C++ program like this:

```
system("gnuplot");
```

It gives the error:

```
'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command. etc.
```

when I try to run gnuplot in cmd, it works fine.

Any one have idea that why gnuplot command in not working with `system()` function in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is probably that the environment you execute your C++ program in doesn't tell your operating system to look in the right places to find your gnuplot executable.

Try the full path to the GNU Plot executable, include the file suffix (.exe) if you're on Windows, or make sure to set the `PATH` environment variable to include the directory in which your gnuplot executable is.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the path to the gnuplot is in your `PATH` environment variable. Or alternatively, you can use the absolut path to it when calling `system()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for answers friends,

I found the solution finally: After editing the environment variable $path, one has to restart the visual studio to get the latest value of environment variable. When I restarted my visual studio, it works.

So when ever you change your any environment variable, just restart visual studio (in case you are using it).

Thanks and kind regards,

Awais